# Trying to remove missing data from a pie chart in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a pie chart using plotly and have it in a shiny app. I am using gender as my labels but want to get rid of missing data that is currently being considered as a 3rd gender. Nothing I have tried so far has worked.

I have tried na.omit, na.rm and ngo[ngo == ""] = NA. The latter worked on a graph above the pie chart so I don't know if this is why it won't work for second graph.

```
output$traffickerGender <- renderPlotly({
    ngo[ngo == ""] = NA
    gender = plot_ly(ngo, labels = ~Trafficker.Gender, type = "pie") 
    gender
  })
```

Remove a slice of the pie chart that is missing data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to filter out the rows that are missing a valid Trafficker.Gender entry.

Option 1: Using dplyr pipes. The filter function below will remove rows containing *either* blank or NA elements in the Trafficker.Gender column:

```
library(dplyr)
output$traffickerGender <- renderPlotly({
   ngo %>% filter(Trafficker.Gender != "") %>% 
                     plot_ly(labels = ~Trafficker.Gender, type = "pie")
})
```

Option 2: using Base R

```
output$traffickerGender <- renderPlotly({
   # if missing entries are a mixture of blank and NA use the following:
   rowsToInclude <- (ngo$Trafficker.Gender != "") && !is.na(ngo$Trafficker.Gender)
   # if missing entries are all "", use rowsToInclude <- (ngo$Trafficker.Gender != "")
   plot_ly(ngo[rowsToInclude,], labels = ~Trafficker.Gender, type = "pie")
})
```